# I'm I being spied on?

Tags: kernel

so lets say am worried that I'm being spied on! 
So I regularly check on my log files. the kern.log reading is not making me feel calm at all... is like my camera is on and sending inputs somewhere I can't find..
now am going to post a part of the log so the more seasoned guys on the forum can help me out with some explanations and if necessary steps to take...
I am not connecting or disconnecting usb but the kernel keeps saying so, is that normal? the kernel keeps logging only the camera..may as well log other devices no? soo fishy to me...

```
 May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3419.381250] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=0295
May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3419.381255] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3419.381258] usb 1-3: Product: Lenovo EasyCamera
May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3419.381260] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Vimicro corp.
May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3419.381843] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (5986:0295)
May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3419.382823] input: Lenovo EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input29
May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3419.416380] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:76e5:43ff:feac:107d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3419.426537] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:76e5:43ff:feac:107d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3419.916073] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 24
May 16 07:46:00 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3420.180341] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3420.292341] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3420.496306] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3420.700145] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 25, error -71
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3420.996076] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3421.132489] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=0295
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3421.132497] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3421.132501] usb 1-3: Product: Lenovo EasyCamera
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3421.132504] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Vimicro corp.
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3421.133044] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (5986:0295)
May 16 07:46:01 mike-Lenovo-U310 kernel: [ 3421.133862] input: Lenovo EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input30
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be suspicious. It's ordinary device detecting and driver loading process by kernel. If you are not sure of your safety you can check out which apps make connections with `netstat -n -A inet -t` and net bandwith usage with `bmon`

Comment: I see that traffic to UDP port 8612 broadcast too on *every* USB device I connect/disconnect. Blocked by my host firewall just like yours. It gives me the creeps... Would love to have an answer on this.

Comment: Some Canon devices and applications do that. In my case my computer was sending UDP traffic from 8612 to 8610 and 8612, everytime I connected or disconnected any USB device. The cause was the "colord-sane" daemon, which knows about my Canon scanner. This happens no matter if the scanner is connected or not. I've heard this also happens with networked printers.